# can't make selected option by default

Tags: php, html, wordpress-theming

I have dynamically generated options select, which adds the selected attribute to a specific option with id value, and i have it generated as desired but while i have an option with `selected` attribute i always get the first option as selected. 
I wrote this function to generate options:

```
function getProjectType($selected = ""){
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'project_type',
    'parent' => 0,
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'id' => 'project_type' ,
    'show_option_all' => false,
) );

?>
<?php if(!empty($terms)){?>

    <label class="fre-field-title" for="project-type"><?php _e('Please define your project type',MR_DOMAIN) ?></label>
    <div class="mr-select-box">
    <select name="project-type" id="project-type" class="mr-chosen-single" required>
    <option value="" disabled hidden><?php _e('Select project type',MR_DOMAIN) ?></option>
    <?php
    foreach($terms as $term){?>
            <option  id="<?php echo $term->slug.'-'.$term->term_id;?>" value="<?php echo $term->term_id ?>"<?php echo ($selected == $term->term_id) ? 'selected' : '' ?>><?php echo $term->name;?></option>
    <?php }?>
    </select>

    </div>

    <?php }
}
```

This function should accept a value and add selected attribute to the option that has this value. Then called it and Here is the generated options:

```
<select name="project-type" id="project-type" class="mr-chosen-single" required="">
    <option value="" disabled="" hidden="">select</option>
    <option id="project-type-image-147" value="147">147</option>
    <option id="project-type-video-145" value="145" selected="">145</option>
    <option id="project-type-website-146" value="146">146</option>
    <option id="project-type-audio-144" value="144">144</option>
</select>
```

As you can see option 145 has selected attribute but and i need it to show as selected but always get the 1st option as selected, while if i copied this generated list in separate html file it will work, why not working when dynamically generated.

Comment: just add selected property. hope it will work..

Comment: <option id="project-type-video-145" value="145" selected>145</option>

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Sorry, i have added more details, you need to consider

Comment: The generated HTML works as expected. No issues here.

Comment: @kousheralampranto actually i already added only selected but it outputs with equal operator

Comment: @connexo yes if you used it directly within html file, but can't get it to work dynamicaly, don't know where the proplem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by others, I've not been able to reproduce your issue. I've copied your HTML snippet and added some JS to play with it. It returns the expected result - "145" and index 2

```js
function byId(id){return document.getElementById(id)}

function testFunc()
{
  var testElem = byId('project-type');
  var selStr = testElem.value;
  var result = -1;
  var options = [...testElem.options];
  
  options.forEach( function(el,idx){if (el.selected) result = idx;} );
  
  var msg = `Val: ${selStr}, Index: ${result}`;
  alert(msg);
}

window.addEventListener('load', onWndLoaded, false);

function onWndLoaded(evt)
{
  testFunc();
}
```

```html
<select name="project-type" id="project-type" class="mr-chosen-single" required="">
    <option value="" disabled="" hidden="">select</option>
    <option id="project-type-image-147" value="147">147</option>
    <option id="project-type-video-145" value="145" selected="">145</option>
    <option id="project-type-website-146" value="146">146</option>
    <option id="project-type-audio-144" value="144">144</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is not the issue because the markup works normaly if copied to extrnal file but while generated dynamicaly, the select attribute has no effect, don't know why

Comment: @Makiomar - Neither do we, how could we? While I'm a little surprised I have to write this, why on earth does your question not include an example that _is_ broken? We can't fix something that works, so posting it seems unhelpful.

Comment: it seems that there is unknown script that is preventing it from working, thank you

Comment: @Makiomar - Ahhhh. I'd suspected that may be the issue. You should easily be able to step through the code in a debugger  to see which what's actually happening and where it departs from expectations. Ctrl-Shift-I opens up the developer-tools in Chrome, dunno about the others.